# Outputting Database Contents after user input

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Im trying to do a Statement where the user would be prompted for the authors name and then all of the authors values would be output, below works but doesn't output anything.

```
  public static void WhichAuthorQry (Connection conn)
 {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

     try {

     Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

     System.out.println("Please enter the Authors name to search:");
     String name = sc.next();

     String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Poet WHERE PoetName='" + name + "'";

     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

     while(rs.next()) {
         System.out.println("Name: " + rs.getString("PoetName"));
         System.out.println("Language: " + rs.getString("Language"));

     }

     }catch (Exception e){
         System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
     }


 }
```

Comment: Please do not concatenate values into a query string, it opens you to SQL Injection. Use prepared statements instead. Also note that the present of a cast (`(Statement)`) indicates you are not importing `java.sql.Statement`, but something else.

Comment: Exploits of a Mom: https://xkcd.com/327/ Little Bobby Tables and OWASP SQL Injection https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to put your query into a prepared statement and offer the user to use wildcards:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Poet WHERE PoetName like ?");
ps.setString(1,name);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery() ;
while ( rs.next() ) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + rs.getString("PoetName"));
    System.out.println("Language: " + rs.getString("Language"));
}
```

Comment: I tried that there and it still didnt output an answer, sorry im so bad at this, checked my tables and the value for the author is there, it just wont output when prompted. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Is the fieldname correct?  Do you get any exception? Does 'name' have a value? It is pretty hard to find out the reason from distance.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest thing I would think of is, does the case of name you enter, match the PoetName?

You could try

```
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Poet WHERE lower(PoetName)= lower('" + name + "')";
```

Comment: It isnt doing the error message so it is working but nothing is coming out, would it be better to put the data through an array and try it like that?

Comment: As  @Mark  and Fredy have suggested, its not a very good way to concatenate. But i guess you are in your baby steps with jdbc, so you could get it working and improve on it.  How about changing  `String name = sc.next(); ` to a string that is set to an existing author with the same case?  `String name = "An author" ;`, just so that you eliminate any non printable characters, not sure which db u r using, you could also try trim function with author `trim ('"+name+"');"`